# Neo4j - apply match to each result of previous match

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Situation: graph with numerous end points each of which has one connection to the main graph. This connection may traverse several intervening **node->relationship->node** before joining the main graph. This final node where each connects has a specific property.

I have a query that walks down this path and finds the node that ultimately joins to the main graph. I have another query that returns a list of the end-point nodes. How would I use the list of nodes from query 2 to feed into query 1 so I could get the results of query 1 for every member of query 2?

Ideally I want something like **FOREACH** but that's out as query 1 begins with a *match* statement. It doesn't make any changes. Something akin to `create outer_list -> each outer_list_member -> run next query and return single result -> repeat with next list_member`

---

- Query 1: `match p=(n {individual end node property})-[r: JOINS*1..5]-(m { joining node property }) return n.name, length(p) as len, m.name order by len limit 1`
  -- this gives me the end node and the joining node (via shortest path)
- Query 2: `match node_list = (n {property of all end nodes})`

I can run **query 1** and get the correct results if I manually specify the unique property ("id") of a given end node. I want to create a list of all end nodes and their connecting node.

Comment: did you ever figure out how to do this? i have a similar need.

Comment: It's been a while but IIRC I did it in code. I don't recall finding a pure-cypher method.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I was thinking I might have to do that  :/

Answer (score 2):

Cypher's `WITH` clause is pretty useful for feeding one query into another.  Maybe that would be useful?

http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-with.html

Comment: Using *with* I can certainly pass the results from 2->1 but it prevents the use of 'limit 1' for each secondary match. If I 'limit 1' I get only one row. Without 'limit 1' I get every combination. I want one result from each.

Comment: Not sure I understand, but maybe you need an aggregation function in the WITH so that you only return one result out of each set?

Answer (score 0):

Shortest Path returns exactly one path each.

```
match (n:Label {prop:value})
match p=shortestPath( (n)-[: JOINS*1..5]-(m:Label2 {prop2:value2}) 
return n.name, length(p) as len, m.name
```

Otherwise you can also use paths as collection expressions and just return 
`head((n1)-[*..5]-(n2))`

expensive operation but you can oder by path length, then aggregate by start node and take the first element of a collect (shortest path is first in the list).

```
...
with n, p
order by length(p)
return n.name, head(collect(p))
```

Comment: There will only be one path in each case so it's not a question of finding *the shortest* - it's more about finding *the nearest* or maybe *the next*.